# How can I simplify this line of code using a common for loop rather than list expansion?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Take a look at the following piece of code:

```
def load_data_k(fname: str, yyy_index: int, **selection):
    selection_key_str = list(selection.keys())[0]
    selection_value_int = selection[selection_key_str]
    print(selection_value_int)
    i = 0
    file = open(fname)
    if "top_n_lines" in selection:
        lines = [next(file) for _ in range(selection_value_int)]
```

first please tell me why is it using `next(file)` here:

```
lines = [next(file) for _ in range(selection_value_int)]
```

then please tell me how can I simplify this line using a normal for-loop rather than a list expansion.

Comment: In what way will a for loop simplify the code?

Comment: @Mr.T, I don't understand this line of code. I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: That makes a list out of the first N lines of the file.  It's not that complicated.  You could, I suppose, use `file.readlines()[:selection_value_int]`, but that reads the entire file into memory, whereas the list comprehension does not.

Comment: @TimRoberts, plz, post this as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet:

```
lines = [next(file) for _ in range(selection_value_int)]
```

expands to:

```
lines = []
for _ in range(selection_value_int):
    lines.append(next(file))
```

However this doesn't simplify anything.

`next(file)` uses File object's generator behaviour
Thus loads some lines without getting whole file

Comment: does your code solve the problem pointed out by TimRoberts in the comments section?

Comment: It does the same thing as your code but you get rid of the list comprehension. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Oh yeah! This is waht I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
with open(fname) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[:selection_value_int]
```

though the entire file is read into memory